# Vertical post Slider using React

Tags: reactjs

I want to show one card at a time on screen in mobile when  swipe on screen then get next card I implement it using react Swappable Views but with this I am only able to swipe in left -right I want to get new card when I swipe up-down for reference I like something (https://inshorts.com/m).Open the site in mobile. Please Help me to show card somthing like this
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

First need to install "react swipeable view" using command
npm i react-swipeable-views
then use the code

```
`<SwipeableViews
  index={0}
containerStyle={{ height: 100%}}
  axis="y" resistance>
  // your content with each content full height
</SwipeableViews>`
```